# BitBurner: How do I turn my array into an argument, or pass to a seperate function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

I'm working on building a script to scan/distribute/hack all servers all at once. My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to pass my first array (spider() in the code) to my second function (probe()). I want to use the first array as the "target" variable in the second function. I've left my comments to explain what I'm thinking and what I've been trying to figure out.

```
/** @param {NS} ns**/

export async function main(ns){

//functions under here to make things pretty
function spider() { //Used to scan all servers
    let serversSeen = ['home']
    for (let i=0; i < serversSeen.length; i++) {
        let thisScan = ns.scan(serversSeen[i]);
        for (let j=0; j < thisScan.length; j++) {
            if (serversSeen.indexOf(thisScan[j]) === -1) {
                serversSeen.push(thisScan[j]);
            } //Make the array an argument to pass into probe function
        }
    }
    return serversSeen;
}
function probe() { //Used to open all server ports, gain root access, and run distro function
    function can(action) {
        return ns.fileExists(action + ".exe", "home"); //Checks for .exes
    }
    spider();
    for (let x=0; x < serversSeen.length;) {
        let target = serversSeen.length;
        let ports = 0;
        if (can( "BruteSSH" )) { ns.brutessh  (target);  ++ports; } //Opens all ports on server//Rewrite ns.brutessh (etc) to be strings
        if (can( "FTPCrack" )) { ns.ftpcrack  (target);  ++ports; }
        if (can( "RelaySMTP")) { ns.relaysmtp (target);  ++ports; }
        if (can( "HTTPWorm" )) { ns.httpworm  (target);  ++ports; }
        if (can( "SQLInject")) { ns.sqlinject (target);  ++ports; }

        if (ns.getServerNumPortsRequired(target) <= ports && ns.hasRootAccess(target) == false) {
            ns.nuke(target);
            ++x
            //create an argument of rooted servers (rootedTarget)
        } else {
            if (ns.hasRootAccess(target) == true) {
            //Push any previously/manually rooted targets to the rootedTarget index(argument)
            }
        }
    }
    return ;//Args of targets (rootedTarget)
}
```

I've looked into making my array an argument but everything I find seems to assume that the array is predefined.

I've tried running the `spider()` function inside of the `probe()` function but that also seems to do nothing.

I also believe I have to rewrite the ns.ftpcrack etc code lines, but for now I am stuck on finding a way to pass the array.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this post looking for something else and noticed no one has replied to you. Your code seems to just look at the length of the array, but not the values of the array. It also seems to have extra steps that you don't need to do, if I'm understanding your intent correctly. So, here is how I would write what you are trying to do.

```
for (let x = 0; x < serversSeen.length; x++) {
    let target = serversSeen[x];
    let ports = 0;
    if (ns.hasRootAccess(target) == false) {
        if (can("BruteSSH")) { ns.brutessh(target); ++ports; } //Opens all ports on server//Rewrite ns.brutessh (etc) to be strings
        if (can("FTPCrack")) { ns.ftpcrack(target); ++ports; }
        if (can("RelaySMTP")) { ns.relaysmtp(target); ++ports; }
        if (can("HTTPWorm")) { ns.httpworm(target); ++ports; }
        if (can("SQLInject")) { ns.sqlinject(target); ++ports; }

        if (ns.getServerNumPortsRequired(target) <= ports) { ns.nuke(target); }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, assuming you didn't already find your answer. :D

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did eventually write something very similar to yours when I did figure it out. I wish I still had the code on my work computer so I could share it

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that scans for each server and returns an array of servers, using the ns.scan(); function. 'hack-script.js' is the hack script i run on the server. Feel free to edit my code, it's a bit sloppy, a bit slow, maybe error prone.

```js
/** @param {NS} ns */
function dpList(ns, current = "home", set = new Set()) 
{
    let connections = ns.scan(current);
    let next = connections.filter(c => !set.has(c));
    next.forEach(n => 
    {
        set.add(n); return dpList(ns, n, set);
    });
    return Array.from(set.keys());
}

export async function main(ns) 
{
    let servers = dpList(ns);
    for (let server of servers)
    {
        ns.scp("hack-script.js", server);
        if(ns.getServerMaxRam(server) > 1 && ns.hasRootAccess(server))
        {
            let threads = Math.floor(ns.getServerMaxRam(server) / 
ns.getScriptRam('hack-script.js', server));
            ns.exec("hack-script.js", server, threads);
        }
        if(!ns.hasRootAccess(server) && ns.getServerMaxRam(server) > 1)
        {
            try
            {
                ns.brutessh(server);
                ns.ftpcrack(server);
                ns.relaysmtp(server);
                ns.httpworm(server);
                ns.sqlinject(server);
            }
            catch {}
            try
            {
                ns.nuke(server);
            }
            catch{}
            let threads = Math.floor(ns.getServerMaxRam(server) / 
ns.getScriptRam('hack-script.js', server));
            ns.exec("hack-script.js", server, threads);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```